# Running Kaa Datacollection Demo on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kaa

I want to run Kaa Data Collection Demo on ubuntu. for this goal i used sandbox and after generate java SDK, I used this document to run application on ubuntu.
https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/
but when i run terminal commands on ubuntu, this error happen. (see picture)
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElwaN.png)

this error in about invalid flag in slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar. could you please help me to solve that?
note: slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar file is independs on my code and for every data collection application we should use that.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this invalid flag error by renaming the **slf4j-simple-1.7.21.jar** with a simple name like **slf4j.jar**. But then it start showing some error. So I would recommend you to use Eclipse. Then add the generated Java SDK jar from Kaa and slf4j-simple.jar as Referenced Jars and compile the code. That's how I program the JAVA apps for Kaa now. Hope it helps!